# sailsjs standalone action to view (Sailsjs V1.0.0)

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js

I have a standalone action which I call from my front end via a button click using CloudSDK, I get my value but the action does not redirect to the view. I have specified the responseType as view in my success exit but this does not seem to work.

Button code in page.js file:

```
clickVerifyBtn: async function(uid) {

  await Cloud.userIdVerify(uid);
},
```

the action

```
module.exports = {


  friendlyName: 'User id verify',


  description: '',


  inputs: {
    uid: {
      description: 'Id of the user',
      type: 'number'
    },   
  },

    exits: {

      success:{
        responseType: 'view',
        viewTemplatePath: 'pages/admin/verification-doc',
      }

    },



  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

    // All done.
    var userdoc = await Photo.findOne({ownerId: inputs.uid, isRemoved:false, photoType:0})
    var imageSrc = '/images/useruploads/'+userdoc.imageFileName;

    return exits.success({imageSrc: imageSrc});


  }


};
```

What is the correct way to achieve this ? Should I submitting my value to the action via the ajax-form component bundled in Sails?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action2 returns the variables not to the view directly but to the view's page instance (your_view.page.js) submitted method.

Comment: Thank you for your input Robertino! The issue here is to actually redirect after running the action and return the result to a new view, not necessarily the view from which the action was called. So, I call the action from view A but I would like the result to be returned to view B.

Comment: I have accepted this answer as it has indeed pushed me to the right direction, just a matter of understanding the res object and the context sailsjs is using it in.

Comment: yep, I started using sailsjs a couple of months back and experienced the same as you, a lot of trial and error :-)